# Should I (could I? would I?) point the answer to my own question to an outside link?

Tags: discussion

Let's say that my answer could be clearly explained with a flash animation of my own devising. Could I just supply a link to the animation?
Uncouth?

Comment: Discounting *idealism*, the question remains the same.

Comment: It's acceptable as a *supplement* to your answer, but not your sole explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, you would try to "convert" the answer into a format which can be directly used on site here.

Either as a "screen-shot" of the site you require or - for animiations - as an animated-GIF. Such images can be direclty uploaded and embedded on site, like f.e. [in this answer here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/dedicated-image-but-dedicated-to-what-who/18317#18317)

If this is not possible, then sometimes some "deposit" sites are used.
There is a bit of gray area here, I think.

In particular for Javascript code, people have used http://jsfiddle.net/, like f.e. as [simulator JS app](http://jsfiddle.net/vwe9kw7j/2/) in [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/the-tilted-labyrinth-can-you-find-the-fastest-path-in-this-3d-puzzle-simulat).

Large amounts of text can also be shared via http://dropbucket.org/.

It is imporatant that these links are "trustworthy" and you would defenitely want to describe the link-destination first.

Sites like *jsfiddle.net* show the source-code, which builds some trust. I would *never ever* visit an obscure link with some "download". I think this would be a no-go.

Comment: An [obscure link](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/should-i-could-i-would-i-point-the-answer-to-my-own-question-to-an-outside-l) is where we hang our hat.

Comment: @Chowzen nice try. I m NOT checking it out. Sure.

Comment: Dang the recursion

Comment: Would you be more prone to click this? [clickable link](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/should-i-could-i-would-i-point-the-answer-to-my-own-question-to-an-outside-l )

Comment: To be clear, I am not starting a fight, @BemyGuest, Just enjoying a spirited debate..

Comment: @Chowzen same here. Thought your comment funny and sought a good reply :-)